# Custom Route Doesn't Get The Query String

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, url-routing

I am trying to do a simple routing as follows:

```
http://localhost:PortNo/Exam/2
```

So in the route config file, I've this:

```
routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Exam",
        url: "Exam/{id}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Exam", action = "Index" },
        namespaces: new[] { "App.Web.Controllers" }
);
```

In the controller:

```
 [HttpGet]
 public ActionResult Index(int id)
 {
    return View(GetQuestions(id));
 }
```

Unfortunately the above routing doesn't get me the query string value but this helps that I don't prefer:

```
ttp://localhost:PortNo/Exam/Index/2
```

Just wasted an hour for this simple thing, anything skipped here? Would appreciate an idea to overcome this.

Answer (score 1):

Please note that `2` is not a query string in the Url  `http://localhost:PortNo/Exam/2`. It is the part of the Url. If you had written `http://localhost:PortNo/Exam?id=2` then `2` would be a query string.

Assuming your route to action is working then change the route to:

```
routes.MapRoute(
     name: "Exam",
     url: "Exam/{id}",
     defaults: new { controller = "Exam", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
     namespaces: new[] { "App.Web.Controllers" }
);
```

Also since your `id` parameter is optional you should have is as a nullable int instead of an int like this:

```
 [HttpGet]
 public ActionResult Index(int? id)
 {
    return View(GetQuestions(id.value));
 }
```

Then you can also check conditions like `if(id.hasvalue)`. Do not have to worry about the zero (0) value.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see anything wrong with your route mapping, unless you have some other route configs you didn't show that conflict with this one:

```cs
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Exam",
    url: "Exam/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Exam", action = "Index" },
    namespaces: new[] { "App.Web.Controllers" }
);
```

This would correctly map the request `http://localhost:PortNo/Exam/2` to the exam controller, index method and set the parameter ID = 2:

[image]